# Force automatic linq to sql classes to have pascal case properties?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, properties, camelcasing, pascalcasing

My SQL database has column names in camel case.
I'm using Linq to SQL with C#.

Is there a way to force auto-generation of properties to be in pascal case?

The camel case properties do not conform to the C# standards, and it's a pain to do it manually each time I need to re-create the classes.

Comment: The [Huagati DBML Tools](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/) offer stuff like that - naming conventions and Linq-to-SQL model refresh and a few more goodies. Not free - but well worth the money, if you're seriously using Linq-to-SQL !

Comment: I guess no chance you can rename your SQL columns?  That sounds like the easiest method.

Comment: @SteveDanner actually simplest method is renaming generated classes in dbml designer

Answer (score 1):

If your database is really big and renaming entities manually is time consuming, then:

- Download [LINQ to SQL templates for T4](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/) and add two files to your project `CSharpDataClasses.tt` and `L2ST4.ttinclude`.
- Rename `` `CSharpDataClasses.tt `` to match your `dbml` file name (e.g. `Northwind.tt`)
- Select `dmbl` file (e.g. `Northwind.dbml`) and remove `MSLinqToSQLGenerator` from `Custom Tool` property.
- Open `L2ST4.ttinclude` and change it as described further
- Select `Northwind.tt` file and press `Ctrl+S` (this will run LINQ 2 SQL classes generation).

**L2ST4.ttinclude file changes:**

Find definition of class `Data` (at the top of file) and paste this code before it:

```
class Lazy
{
   public static string FirstLetterToUpper(string str)
   {
       return Char.ToUpper(str[0]) + str.Substring(1);
   }
}
```

Then find definition of class `Table` and in constructor replace `Member` property initialization with

```
Member = Lazy.FirstLetterToUpper((String)xe.Attribute("Member"));
```

Find class `Class` and in constructor replace `Name` property initialization with

```
Name = Lazy.FirstLetterToUpper((String) xe.Attribute("Name"));
```

And last, find class `Association` and in its constructor set

```
typeName = Lazy.FirstLetterToUpper((String) xe.Attribute("Type"));
```

---

PS If you really lazy, then use [this L2ST4.ttinclude file](http://www.mediafire.com/?5pfamnrb3y506r9) already changed by me :)

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework 4.0 and sql server. I have the similar issue.. the properties are all lower case and contains underscore... similarly the classes too as the entity framework generate classes in the name as such it is found in database... 

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Xavier I don't know if T4 templates work with EF 4.0. But you can change property names generation with T4.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest LINQ to SQL templates for T4 project [l2st4.codeplex.com](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/). You can customize it as you wish.